# pass data on a click event on foreach produced divs

Tags: jquery, events, click

I'm fetching data from an API and run it through a Foreach loop in PHP to produce a list of cards.

When someone clicks on the card, is there a way to get the PHP values to be sent to jQuery so that I can execute another process from then?

For example an ajax call to send data on click.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <?php foreach ($call_array ['events'] as $data ) { ?>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <?php echo '<h2 class="card-title">'. $data ['name']['text'] .'</h2>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <a href="<?php echo $data['event_url'];?>" role="button">Go Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php  } ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attributes to keep the data in your div.

```
<div class="card" data-name="<?php echo $data['name'];?>" data-url="<?php echo $data['event_url'];?>">
    <div class="card-header">
      <?php echo '<h2 class="card-title">'. $data ['name']['text'] .'</h2>'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <a href="<?php echo $data['event_url'];?>" role="button">Go Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then access it this way with Jquery:

```
$(".card").on("click", function(e) {
   $(this).attr("data-url"); //contains url of card clicked
   $(this).attr("data-name"); //contains name of card clicked
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Sorry that I didn't explain it properly. I'm fetching data from an API and run it through a foreach loop in php to produce a list of cards. When someone clicks the card, I need that card information to execute another process.

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible solution to your problem now that I understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the values to the click event, you could read them from the DOM within the event handler. Something like this:

```js
$('.card a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $(this).closest('.card').find('.card-title').text();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  
  console.log(name, url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="card-title">Name A</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <a href="#event-url1" role="button">Go Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="card-title">Name B</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <a href="#event-url2" role="button">Go Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```